# Prevent 32bit setup project running on 64bit machine

Tags: visual-studio, setup-project

I have two Visual Studio Setup and Deploymemnt projects for 32 and 64bit targets. How do I prevent the 32bit installer being run on a 64 bit machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here: http://blogs.flexerasoftware.com/installtalk/2010/11/using-msi-launch-conditions-to-prevent-installation-on-unsupported-windows-platforms.html

Thanks Alan!

- Add a Launch Condition
- Set Condition property to VersionNT64 or Not VersionNT64 as appropriate
- Add the message